# How to select only changing values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

It's hard to explain even with my English so I'm going to show what I want through the following example :

For example I have a table like:

**Date**  **ID**  **Val**

```
SomeDate.... 1  0
SomeDate.... 2  0
SomeDate.... 2  0
SomeDate.... 1  0
SomeDate.... 1  0
SomeDate.... 1  1
SomeDate.... 1  1
SomeDate.... 2  1
SomeDate.... 1  0
SomeDate.... 2  0
SomeDate.... 1  0
SomeDate.... 1  1
```

So **I want to register only changing values** like :

```
SomeDate.... 1  1 //registered 0 -> 1 for ID 1
SomeDate.... 2  1 //registered 0 -> 1 for ID 2
SomeDate.... 1  0 //registered 1 -> 0 for ID 1
SomeDate.... 2  0 //registered 1 -> 0 for ID 2
SomeDate.... 1  1 //registered 0 -> 1 for ID 1
```

**MS SQL SERVER 2008**

maybe someone an example or any thoughts as to how can I realize these changes, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to find all the unique combinations of ID and Val?

Comment: @Abe Miessler not , I corrected example, I want to register the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following might do the trick.

```
;With RankedDates As
    (
    Select T1.[Date], T1.ID, T1.Val
        , Row_Number() Over( Partition By T1.ID Order By T1.[Date] ) As Num
    From SourceTable As T1
    )
Select T1.[Date], T1.ID
    , T1.Val As InitialValue
    , T2.Val As ChangedToValue
    , T2.[Date] As ChangedDate
From RankedDates As T1
    Join RankedDates As T2
        On T2.ID = T1.ID
            And T2.Num = T1.Num + 1
            And T2.Val <> T1.Val
Order By T1.ID
```